# Are these groupoids isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Are these groupoids isomorphic?

1. $(\Bbb Z, x \circ y = x+2y)$ and $(\Bbb Z, x \circ y = x+3y)$
2. $(\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}, x \circ y = x+y+xy)$ and $(\Bbb Z_{> 0}, x \circ y = xy)$

My solution attempt for 1 question:

I need to find such bijective function (or show that such function doesn't exist) $f: \Bbb Z \mapsto \Bbb Z$ that
$f(x+2y) = f(x)+3f(y)$.

For $y = x$ we get: $f(3x) = 4f(x)$.

Obvious solution for this is constant, but using wolfram I also found such function: $f(x) = c\!\cdot\!4^{\log(x)/\log(3) - 1}$.

Both of these obviously do not fit the requirements. I guess such function doesn't even exist, but I don't know how to show that. Any hints?

Comment: For the first pair, since $f(x+2)=f(x)+3f(1)$, you only need to know the values of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$. So, think mod $3$ and show that $f$ cannot be surjective. For the second pair, consider the map $x \mapsto 1+x$.

Comment: Here's a bit of a hint: if we take x=0 and y=2n for n in Z, then we need f(2n)=f(0+2n)=f(0)+3f(n)=3f(n).

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang 1)$f(1+2*0) = f(1)+3*f(0)$ and 2) $f(0+2*1) = f(0)+3*f(1)$. That leads to 1)$f(1) = f(1)+3*f(0)$ and 2)$f(1) = f(0)+3*f(1)$. 1 - 2: $0 = -2f(1) + 2f(0) => f(0)  = f(1)$, but because f should be injective,  1 need to be equal to 0, which is not true. Is this right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first pair, we need to find a bijective function (or show that such function doesn't exist) $f:\Bbb Z\mapsto\Bbb Z$ such that
$f(x+2y)=f(x)+3f(y)$.

For $y=-x$, we get that $\;f(-x)=f(x)+3f(-x)\;\;\;\forall x\in\Bbb Z\;,$

$f(x)=-2f(-x)\;\;\;\forall x\in\Bbb Z\;,\quad\color{blue}{(1)}$

$f(-x)=-2f(x)\;\;\;\forall x\in\Bbb Z\;.\quad\color{blue}{(2)}$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, it follows that

$f(x)=4f(x)\;\;\;\forall x\in\Bbb Z\;,$ hence ,

$f(x)=0\;\;\;\forall x\in\Bbb Z\;.$

Consequently , it cannot exist any bijective function $f:\Bbb Z\mapsto\Bbb Z$ such that
$f(x+2y)=f(x)+3f(y)\,$.